# I make ten phone calls (in) a day

Tags: prepositions

I was just taking this grammar test and there's this question on it:

Which of these sentences are correct:

1. I make ten phone calls a day.
2. I make ten phone calls **in** a day.

Aren't they both correct? I make ten phone calls a day probably means I make 10 phone calls per day, and I don't know how to describe what the other sentence means other than just to use I make 10 phone calls in a day. 
Is there a difference in their meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the content may make this clearer. If I asked you how fast you ran the 100 metre dash, you may say "I ran ten metres a second" but you wouldn't say "I ran ten metres **in** a second". The former talks about what you did throughout the race while the latter talks about what you did in one second of the race.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence #1 is clearly correct and natural.

I wouldn't say that #2 is grammatically *incorrect* (I can imagine contexts where it would be OK), but it does sound a bit off. I think the reason is that the habitual aspect of "I make" conflicts with the specificity of "*a* day".

To see this, let us put both sentences in the past tense, and consider:

## 3: I made ten phone calls a day.

## 4: I made ten phone calls in a day.

What do these mean? #3 talks about a *habitual* past action: "Back then, I was such a good salesman -- I made ten phone calls a day, and my boss always told people I was his most valuable employee."

In contrast, #4 talks about **one** past action on **one particular day**: "I was a pretty good salesman back then, but then this *one* day I was simply on fire: I made ten phone calls in a day!"

From this we can see why #2 doesn't quite work: "a day" here suggests a perfective aspect (one event which is completed), but "I make" is a habitual present. You could say "I can make 10 phone calls in a day", though.

(By the way, as a native speaker, your analysis feels totally natural to me, including your difficulty in putting your finger on how exactly to describe what #2 means -- I went through precisely the same thoughts.)

Comment: Following your 3: and 4: fantasies, I add **5: I made 10 phone calls today**.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but the first one makes much more sense.

> I make ten phone calls a day.

This means that *every day* I make ten calls. It may be an approximation or average. It describes a continued experience, and would be an answer to the question "how much do you use the phone in your job?". It is a meaningful statement for many people.

> I make ten phone calls in a day.

This would make sense as an answer to the question "if you have to make ten phone calls, how much time does it take?" It does not describe a continuous experience and does not mean *every day*. It is probably not a sentence many people would use.

Since this is a test, the likely answer is #1.